# jquery mobile 1.1.0 renders garbage characters on page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile site with a few simple pages that I can navigate in-between. The problem is that jquery mobile renders a few garbage chars " â€‹" to DOM after my last page. The garbage is always the same, sitting on top-left corner of the page, and visible between I page transitions. Maybe worth noting is that I'm using fixed footer.

Anyone experiencing the same?

Pom

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you run your code through a html [validator](http://validator.w3.org). I recently had the same problem. It was caused by an unclosed div in my case.